# Nodemon is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am trying to get my nodemon to start running. But somehow it doesn't run and it have no error message and it's pretty frustrating.

Please see my package.json below:

```
{
  "name": "umbrella_maintenance",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app-express.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

I tried running `npm run start` but it simply do not work. No error message no nothing.
[image: Screenshot of terminal]

My app runs fine when I try to start with `node app-express.js`, but doesn't work when it's nodemon. Any advice?

Comment: Btw, you did a really good job describing your question and providing enough information that it was easy to see what the problem was.

Comment: @Teng did u read [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) docs.It is very clearly written  
 `nodemon  ./server.js localhost 8080`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) says that you need to run nodemon like this `nodemon [your node app]`. So in your case: `nodemon app-express.js`. There are a variety of other useful options for nodemon. It's worth reading the documentation.

Comment: There is error with that command too: `zsh: command not found: nodemon`

Comment: @TengBangWei Have you modified your `start` script in `package.json` to be `nodemon app-express.js` and then run it using `npm run start`?

Answer (score 1):

nodemon help web server shows status. When an error occurs or web server runs well then nodemone shows logs on console. But nodemon can't run web server if the exact path isn't put on command. So nodemon helps node running web server which is executed by `node path/yourApp.js`.

To execute nodemon, type `nodemon path/yourApp.js`.